# Reqular expression begin and end of string

Tags: regex

I need check that string begins with a digit and ends with a digit, even the length is one symbol.

Examples:

```
"1" => true
"1a1" => true
"1a" => false
"a1" => false
```

Answer (score 4):

This should work:

```
^[0-9](.*[0-9])?$
```

Answer (score 2):

Try something like:

```
^[0-9].*?[0-9]$ | ^[0-9]+$
```

The first part matches digit something digit, the second digits

Answer (score 1):

If you are using perl, the look behind assetions may be used

```
^[0-9].*(?<=[0-9])$
```

If you need to use standard regex you can use:

```
^[0-9](.*[0-9])?$
```

more details about look behind see [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this would work for you:

`^\d[^&]*\d$`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check that you have only one digit, something like this should work :

```
^[0-9]$
```

edit : since you've edited your post, here's a new proposition :

```
^([0-9].*)?[0-9]$
```

Comment: Thanx a lot, it's the great sample!

Answer (score 0):

```
^\d.*\d$|^\d$
```

Assuming `^` and `$` mean the beginning and the end of the string in your regex dialect. Otherwise use `\A` and `\Z` or whatever your regex dialect uses for the beginning and the end of the string.

Or in cases like java's `match`, where regexen are anchored by default, you can just use `\d.*\d|\d`.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to read the CodeProject articles on RegEx [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/regextutorial.aspx) and [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/expresso.aspx).